# URLConnection.getContent with HTML file

Tags: java, servlets, httpurlconnection

When I use something like:

```
URL url = new URL(a_url);
URLConnection url_conn = url.openConnection();
Object content = url_conn.getContent();
```

and the MIME type of the file retrieved is HTML or XML I debugged that
`content` at run-time will contain an instance of:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream
```

Now if I want to use `instanceof` on that instance how can I do?

```
if (content instanceof PlainTextInputStream)
{
...
}  
else if(content instanceof ImageProducer)
{
...
}
else if(content instanceof ???) {}
```

Comment: Why? All you need is the content-type and the data. The content-type is in a header: the data is in the input stream. You don't have to interrogate the input stream class at all.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'll do that, but, for now, for educational purposes only, how a nested class like sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream
can be instantiated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not depend of implementation classes. It will break someday.

I think this how you should do it based on the request headers:

```
URLConnection url_conn = url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection http_url_conn = (httpURLConnection )url.openConnection();

String contentType = http_url_conn.getContentType()

  if(contentType.contains("text/plain")){
    //handle plain text
    .....
  } else if(contentType.contains("images/jpeg")){
    //handle image
    ......
  }
```

**Read more about Content-Type here:**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: Yes, thanks this is also a good solution. However I wish to know how to access to that type... maybe something like this? content.getClass().toString().equals("class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream")

Comment: The implementation classes can change anytime. Not a good practice.